# Error while loading class when using Stanford Topic Modeling Toolkit (TMT)

Tags: java, scala, java-7, stanford-nlp, topic-modeling

I have tried JDK7-Update40 and JDK8, but still cannot run the test codes from the TMT website.

Everytime I click 'run', it give error messages as below:

> error: error while loading CharSequence, class file 'C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre8\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken
>   (bad constant pool tag 15 at byte 1470)

And I using the wrong JDK? What specific version should I use?

Can anyone help me out?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same problem.
The way I see it, sbt does not support java8.
Let me describe you my work around.
There are several jdk's installed on my machine.
So I've opened the command line, set `JAVA_HOME` variable
to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55',
simply typing

`SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55`

and had another go with `sbt` command. That worked for me.
Hope, that will help.